# Retrieve and integrate Webservices data into Grails Models

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, grails, model, integration

I wanted to know how can I handle in a neat and modular way the follow situation, using Grails:

I have some data in a local DB (Let's say Books, Authors, Reviews) and I need to enhance that data with information coming from one or more external WS. There can be different scenarios:

1. Enhancing properties of an entity (e.g. I don't have the Book publishing year in the database, so I need to get it from a WS every time the user wants a Book)
2. Federate the entities coming from the DB and from the WSs (e.g for each Book I have some reviews in local, but I can get more of them from external WSs)

What it is the best way to handle this problem in Grails?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit broad (we don't know what kind of webservices you are trying to consume), but I guess I would :

- Use [groovyWS](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS) for each consumed webservice if they are SOAP based, or use [RestClient](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html) if they are RESTful (you can use the [Rest plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest) if you want, but it looks like it hasn't been updated for a while...)
- Create a Grails Service to handle the logic of querying both the local database and the webservices... doing something like :

  ```
  class BookService {

      def bookWS

      def findByAuthor = { author ->
          def books = []
          // From local db
          books << Book.findAllByAuthor(author);

          // From a webservice 
          books << bookWS.findBooksByAuthor(author);
          return books
      }

  }
  ```
- Use my local bookservice in my controller actions

  ```
  class BookController {
      def bookService

      def list() {
          def author = Author.findByName(params.author)
          [allBooks : bookService.findByAuthor(author)]
      } 
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now comes the real question: what kind of objects the bookWS should return? JSON objects (assuming REST+JSON)? Book models? Would it be better if I create an intermediate Book class to abstract from the underlying data source?

Comment: Well in my example I'm assuming your WS stub (bookWS) has a method that converts the remote webservice response into a Book model in your grails app. The logic of conversion is up to you...

Comment: There is an example here : http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+the+client+with+complex+objects